# how to get blob size in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table where i am saving images as blob

now the issue is, how can i get the size of the blob in each tuple.

is there any query to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_content) FROM test_blob WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT  OCTET_LENGTH(blob_tablename) FROM...`